# How can I disable one of the particular value in selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a requirement in which I need to show multiple account related to a customer in a dropdown menu. If the account is not active , I can not able to select it , When I try to select it should show some messages.

Do it possible_

Comment: Please post your existing HTML and JS.

Comment: Please show us your attempts so far, and their results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose it's this easy?

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" disabled>Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

in which case with jQuery you can use

```
//1.6+
$("option .with-class-you-choose").prop('disabled', true);
//1.5 and below
$("option .with-class-you-choose").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged Javascript, here's a JS solution for ya.

https://jsfiddle.net/scheda/vh7dgenv/

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].dataset.enabled == 'false') {
        options[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```